# Recursive method to find the number of appereances in a number

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static boolean countExactly(int num, int digit, int count) {
    if(digit <= 9) {
        return false;
    }
    if(num % 10 == digit) {
        countExactly(num % 10 + num / 10, digit, count++);
    }
    return true;
}
```

What's wrong with my code???
I'm trying to write a recursive method to find the number of appereances in a number.
Write a recursive function that encodes a positive integer num, Spain digit from another integer
No Negative Counting. The function returns true if the digit number appears exactly number number
Count times, otherwise return false.

Example:input:122231 digit:2 count:3 output:true

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: On this input I get false

Answer (score 1):

Given below are the problems with your approach:

1. You are passing `count++` in the recursive call which will always be passed as `count` and then the value will be incremented i.e. the incremented value will never be used. It should be either `++count` or `--count` depending on your logic.
2. You are calling `countExactly(num % 10 + num / 10, digit, count++)` which is like calling a void function/method. It is syntactically correct but it doesn't serve any purpose in your program?

You should do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(countExactly(122231, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(countExactly(122231, 2, 2));
        System.out.println(countExactly(122231, 2, 4));
        System.out.println(countExactly(1222231, 2, 4));
        System.out.println(countExactly(2222231, 2, 4));
        System.out.println(countExactly(2222231, 2, 5));
        System.out.println(countExactly(2222231, 2, 3));
    }

    static boolean countExactly(int num, int digit, int count) {
        if ((num == digit && count == 1) || (num != digit && num <= 9 && count == 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (num <= 9) {
            return false;
        }
        if (num % 10 == digit) {
            return countExactly(num / 10, digit, --count);
        } else {
            return countExactly(num / 10, digit, count);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
false
true
false
true
false
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
public static boolean countExactly(int num, int digit, int count) {
    if (num <= 9 ) {
        return (digit==num && count==1) || (digit!=num && count==0) ;
    }
    if (num % 10 == digit) {
        count--;
    }
    return countExactly( num / 10, digit, count);
}
```

Tried with input values

- 2, 2, 1
- 122231 , 2, 3
- 12231 , 2, 2
- 1, 2, 0